# Is the service of drone.io isolated for each build or shared?

Tags: go, drone.io

The [service](https://docs.drone.io/examples/service/postgres/) of drone.io is a way to include some dependent service into the pipeline.

**I would like to know if the services will be created for each build, so Is the service isolated for each build or shared?**

I already tried to find it via documentation of services but there is not this information there.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
```

I expect that each build creates its own service to keep the things separated.

After I had talked to the core developers I discoreved the answer and now I am sharing here as well

> "each pipeline execution gets its own dedicated network. The network
>   is created when a pipeline starts ,and destroyed when the pipeline
>   completes" - Brad Rydzewski

Answer (score 1):

I am including the Brad Rydzewski's answer and I hope this help someone.

"each pipeline execution gets its own dedicated network. The network is created when a pipeline starts ,and destroyed when the pipeline completes"
 - Brad Rydzewski

Answer (score 0):

Services are isolated for each build but they are shared by the steps in a pipeline. They are only started when your build starts and killed when all the steps complete.

Services are like steps only but they get detached and drone doesn't care about their success/failure. You can also manually detach a step https://docs.drone.io/user-guide/pipeline/services/#detached-steps